# bootstrap-sass + gulp: Media query expression must begin with '('

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm having a problem here with bootstrap-sass. I'm trying to compile bootstrap via Gulp and some other scss libraries in my `style.scss` file, but it throws me this error:

```
Message:
    css/dev/style.scss
Error: media query expression must begin with '('
        on line 1 of css/dev/style.scss
>> @import 'breakpoint-slicer'
   ---------------------------^

Details:
    formatted: Error: media query expression must begin with '('
        on line 1 of css/dev/style.scss
>> @import 'breakpoint-slicer'
   ---------------------------^

    column: 28
    line: 1
    file: /home/nano/Sandbox/bolt-seed/theme/own-theme/css/dev/style.scss
    status: 1
    messageFormatted: css/dev/style.scss
Error: media query expression must begin with '('
        on line 1 of css/dev/style.scss
>> @import 'breakpoint-slicer'
   ---------------------------^
messageOriginal: media query expression must begin with '(' relativePath: css/dev/style.scss
```

I just make a `_variables.scss` copy on my root styles folder (without changes for now) and i getting the error. Same if i include the `breakpoint-slicer` in my imports.

Here are my gulp task and my `style.scss`

#### gulp task

```
gulp.task('sass-build', () => {
  return gulp.src('./css/dev/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [
        './assets/bootstrap-sass/assets',
        './assets/breakpoint-slicer/stylesheets',
      ],
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

#### style.scss:

```
@import 'breakpoint-slicer'

@import 'variables'
@import 'bootstrap'

body {
  padding: 50px
}
```

All the assets are managed by Bower in the `assets` folder. Any idea, or hint about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The could be few reasons. One is that the file isn't where you think it is in relation to gulpfile. I've just recreated the issue locally, and unless I had a correct `includePaths` it wasn't working.

incorrect: (stylesheet.scss)

[image]

When I corrected it, files was imported without any problems:

[image]

e.g.

```
.pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'nested',
    includePaths: [
        './bower_components/breakpoint-slicer/stylesheets'
    ]
}))
```

Are you sure the gulpfile is correctly reading that path?

If you are 100% correct that url is fine, then you need to re-visit your sass file - where you include the partial - I've noticed that you don't have semicolons - they are really needed at the end of each import. Put them in and then your code should be fine

no semicolon - failed task

[image]

with semicolon - task building just fine:

[image]

Comment: The problem was your second hint: semicolons. I'm coming from stylus and it's my habit don't use the semicolons... so, thanks! that was something very little but i could not see it.

Answer (score 6):

Also happens if you forget to add a ***semicolon ;*** after an `@import "xyz";`